# How to configure google vision api with tika parser

Tags: python-3.x, apache, apache-tika, google-vision

I am trying to parse images using the Apache tika-parser in python, but sometimes I get content as "none". But when I try the same image with Google the vision API it gives me a good response.

Is it possible to integrate tika with Google vision API? If yes then how using python?

Comment: Did you turn on the Tesseract OCR support?

Comment: Yes, And it's working fine.But I want to configure g cloud vision .Is this is possible